# Onde encontro o arquivo styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Eu tenho um aplicativo bem simples que roda um arquivo html. Estou querendo muito mudar a cor da barra de status, porque a parte superior e inferior padrão em preto é horrível para a paleta de cores da página mostrada. Eu não tenho ideia sobre Android e não posso começar a aprender agora, mas tentei seguir as respostas, como nesta questão aqui no Stack Overflow: [How to change the status bar color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android).
Porém, não consigo nem mesmo encontrar o arquivo styles.xml que é indicado para se colocar os parâmetros dentro. Tentei criar a pasta "value" com o arquivo styles.xml dentro, mas só corrompeu o app, como eu imaginava que ia acontecer.

Assim é como é visto a árvore de arquivos deste meu app (gerado pelo Website to APK Builder):

[image: árvore de arquivos]

O que faço para realizar isso? Por favor, me ajudem!

Obs: tentei as edições pelo Android Studio.

Para mais detalhe, aqui está o .apk: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yyvjq2_VbjTOAhVg7nRHkGgGcx-pGxNe)

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode testar criando um projeto novo no Android Studio tanto em java quando em kotlin, dentro do diretório res por default tem um diretório values (voce comentou value, não sei se o S que faltou pode ter sido seu problema). Dentro deste diretório values estão alguns arquivos como strings.xml, dimn.xml, colors.xml e styles.xml

Voce pode adicionar outros files uteis ao seu projeto ali... exemplo esse folder que tenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Avallone. Eu percebi que no projeto por padrão já tem o res/values/styles.xml . O problema é que não sei mesclar com "meu" app. digo "meu" pq ele foi gerado no programa Website to APK Builder, eu não sei nem pra onde vai o Android rsrs daí, por ser uma aplicação muito simples eu pensei que seria simples fazer isso também... porém não consegui resultado a dias :/